# No caves in Minecraft Pocket?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

During my survival playthrough have noticed that there are no caves in my **infinite** Minecraft World.

Caves are underground areas where mobs are able to spawn and often include water and/or lava streams and valuable minerals. I reached the bedrock level and could only find lava but no open areas where found.

[Some websites claim](http://www.hardcoregamer.com/2014/07/10/major-update-released-for-minecraft-pocket-edition-adds-caves-villages-more/93540/) that the 0.9 Update included "optional" caves.

The map is an **infinite world** generated in Minecraft PE 0.10.

I'm unable to find an option to enable caves in Minecraft PE 0.11 for Android.

Are caves uncommon to Minecraft PE due to memory constrains or this is a bug?

Comment: I have caves in my game, never seen an option for them though. In 0.9 I never did find caves nor the option. But in 0.11 and 0.12 I find more caves than I think are necessary *and more than my PC version.

Comment: Oh, you should have an option for classic and infinite generation. Classic I don't think has caves. I play infinite all the time now instead.

Comment: Did you use classic or infinite generation?

Comment: It's an infinite world.

Comment: Caves are said to be the most common generated structure in PE atm (according to mojang) and every world I created in 0.9+ had more caves in it than I prefered (I think they need to reduce the caves) I'm unable to even reproduce the problem on any versions with random seeds. Could you provide your seed and the  EXACT config option used to ORIGINALLY generate the world (would generation options after creation) and I'll see if I can reproduce.

Comment: Also, what device and what version of iOS or Android, I've heard rumor that some devices have world generation issues with PE

Comment: I want to find you a solution, give you a +1 and hope somebody else might also contribute. But please include the additional information from my former comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the update to Pocket Edition which includes infinite world generation and caves to say the least, when selecting old generation the game uses the world generator from prior to the update. This means that you will get no caves in this variation.

If you wish to have caves included the world has to have been created after update 0.9 and must have had the 'infinite' world option selected. After creation this option can not be changed and is not retroactive either.

If you change the world from old to infinite after initial creation you will get an effect similar to PC version when world generation is changed. The original area remains unchanged, then world generation is 'broken' at the old generated world and from there you will have infinite world with caves. (Tested in version 0.11 and 0.12)

This applies to ALL version and devices of the Pocket Edition, including Windows 10 version, Android and iOS.

Comment: Thank you @ydobonebi I did some exhaustive digging and was able to find a cave far from the spawn point. The surrounding area near the original spawn location is "flat". The world is infinite and I never switcher from classic to infinite. It might have been a bug in 0.10 and after updating to 0.11 the world generator added some caves when I moved far enough. The device is Android 4.1.2.